# Using Python Requests to download CSV file after authentication

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, python-requests

I'm trying to programmatically download a '.csv' file from the web.  I receive a 200 Response with the following code.

```
import requests
url = 'http://eoddata.com/data/filedownload.aspx?e=NYSE&sd=20180722&ed=20180722&d=5&k=xh2mnktdc4&o=d&ea=1&p=0'
user, password = '..', '..'
resp = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password))
```

When submitting this URL in the browser, the '.csv' file auto-downloads.  I'm trying to get my application to store the file locally.  I don't know the file's end location so I'm having difficulty saving it.

I've added the HTTP Live Headers extension which gives me this:

```
GET /data/filedownload.aspx?e=AMEX&sd=20180719&ed=20180719&d=5&k=n4vic5se64&o=d&ea=1&p=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: eoddata.com
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=drbcwljllaf3xdwdlvqzfvl1;EODDataAdmin=01438A3826CBEEC6085BF7B27AEB1BE6AF337FFBF3E3E33AA1D882D39FB92555E8370DD45631B3F8CAD5289C5C46DB28C99B44DC8253A78D659EB165ADC55A1D6E4C20FA81051908E6BE82143EA5398662779546BE4C31C6F32833C5558F23C9A30D0CA16A703CB939FC6D77A0FB0CB017DDEEA832A1A0CC228B61777295C58CA52AF78B472B9D2FC19E78770DEBD346E9B05F02C65F96EE22C3E55B083FC4A1311FA12B223CC2899D6166E1284AD95E
DNT: 1
Referer: http://eoddata.com/download.aspx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
content-disposition: attachment;filename="AMEX_20180719.csv"
Content-Length: 93840
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Wed, 25 Jul 2018 13:54:31 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Any help in saving the intended file is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I would like to point out this line in the headers response: `content-disposition: attachment;filename="AMEX_20180719.csv"`  Does this make a difference, or no?

Comment: Can you check by using stream as an argument to get. 
resp = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password), stream=True) and then use iter_content() to download chunks

Comment: I think you are suggesting the same thing as @Sam.  If so, it did not work.

Content-disposition is an attachment, do you know if that's an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Since your request seems to be going through, all you have left to do is actually downloading the file. Here is how I usually download files using requests:

```
import requests

def download_file(url, user, password, file_path):
    with requests.get(url, stream = True, auth = (user, password)) as response:
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size = 1024):
                f.write(chunk)
```

Don't forget to end file_path with .csv in this case.

Comment: Thank you.  It seems that there is no content in the response from this URL.  'for chunk in ...' prints nothing.

Comment: Interesting. Sometimes I have had trouble downloading via direct link because the site expects certain headers to be present in the request. Looking at your info in your question, maybe the site wants the `Referer` header to be correctly set to `http://eoddata.com/download.aspx`? Couldn't hurt to try. You can add headers to the request by adding a `headers` keyword argument to the `requests.get()` call, passing in a dictionary of header name, header value pairs. It's also possible that the cookies are required.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import requests, urllib
from tqdm import tqdm

def download_file(url):

    filename = "FILENAME.csv"
    print("Downloading %s ..." % filename)

    with open(filename, "wb") as handle:
        for data in tqdm(response.iter_content()):
            handle.write(data)

    print("Download complete for %s!" % filename)

username = "USERNAME"
password = "PASSWORD"

data_credentials = {'user_id': username, 'password': password}
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'}

login_url = "https://mywebsite.com/login/"

requests_session = requests.Session() # create a requests Session

response = requests_session.post(login_url, headers=headers, data=data_credentials) # log in to the requests Session so that you can reuse it

download_url = "http://www.downloadmyfile.com/something.csv"

response = requests_session.get(download_url, timeout=(15,15))

download_file(response.url) # run function to download file
```

Comment: I would try this, but I don't know the download url endpoint.  Am I missing it in the HTTP Live Headers block?

Comment: The URL that I have is clearly the issue.  I don't know how to parse the direct link to "AMEX_20180719.csv" from the HTTP Live Headers response in my question.